# No Route Matches Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I've been trying to set up Chartkick with Active Admin to set up dashboards for users. I believe I have everything set up correctly based on other answers I've found but I keep getting a routing error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/chartkick.js"). Below are examples of my files.

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

*active_admin.js.coffee*

```
#= require chartkick
```

*dashboard*

```
h3 'Test' do
    @metric = Model.group(:parameter).count
    render partial: 'metrics/partial_name', locals: {metric: @metric}
end
```

*metrics/_partial_name.html.haml*

```
=javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
=pie_chart metric
```

I can't figure out where the error is coming from. Please help!

Comment: you need to run `bundle install` to install the chartkick gem. https://github.com/masweetman/issue_charts/issues/21#issuecomment-307839236

Answer (score 0):

Try to type `bundle` and then reload the server.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to `bundle install`. there is also some configurations you need to do application.js files.

Here's a link to their Github with more info on that: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick